# python multiprocessing slow

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have some code that parallelizes calls to a function. Inside the function, I check if a file exists, if not then I create it, else I do nothing.

I find that if the files do exist, then calling multiprocessing.process has a fairly huge time penalty compared to a simple for loop. Is this expected or is there something I can do to reduce the penalty?

```
def fn():
    # Check if file exists, if yes then return else make the file
    if(not(os.path.isfile(fl))):
        # processing takes enough time to make the paralleization worth it
    else:
        print 'file exists'


pkg_num = 0
total_runs    = 2500
threads = []

while pkg_num < total_runs or len(threads):
    if(len(threads) < 3 and pkg_num < total_runs):
        t = multiprocessing.Process(target=fn,args=[])
        pkg_num = pkg_num + 1
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    else:
        for thread in threads:
            if not thread.is_alive():
                threads.remove(thread)
```

Comment: dont spawn a new one for every file that will take forever ... have each one check a hundred files or something ....

Comment: Are you reading each file inside of that if statement? Disk I/O (like reading the files) doesn't parallelize well; you can't read from different parts of your HDD in parallel, so you'll be jumping back and forth between each file as your worker processes execute. With a spinning disk this is going to hurt performance quite a bit. If you're going a bunch of CPU-bound work after you read it, maybe that makes up for it. Definitely something to keep in mind, though. And as Joran mentioned, constantly spinning up new processes as others exit adds overhead. Use a `multiprocessing.Pool` instead.

Comment: One more thing: You're removing items from `threads` while you iterate over it, which has undefined behavior in Python and will likely cause incorrect behavior.

Comment: thanks dano, will multiprocessing.pool reduce the overhead or will i still need to implement some mechanism like @Joran Beasley suggested...

Comment: @user308827 `multiprocessing.Pool` will create a fixed number of processes that will handle all of the tasks you give it. So you just start `N` processes at the beginning of your program, and they continue to run the whole time. If you pass a list of files to `pool.map`, it will chunk the list and send the chunks to each worker process, which will reduce IPC overhead, as well.

Comment: thanks @dano, i moved my code to multiprocessing.pool and map last night and it does make a huge difference. the code is much simpler and cleaner too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fair bit of overhead to bringing up processes -- you've got to weigh the overhead of creating those processes against the performance benefits that you'll gain from making the tasks concurrent. I'm not sure that there's enough of a benefit for a simple OS call for it to be worthwhile.

Also, for the sake of future generations, you should really check out [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html); way, way cleaner. If you use 2.7, you can back port it.

Comment: Even just using `multiprocessing.Pool` would clean this up enough. It's not super clear from the example, but there is a comment that says `# processing takes enough time to make the paralleization worth it`, I assume that means there's some processing going on in there beyond the `os.path.isfile` call. Hard to say if it's enough to outweigh the process spawning overhead, though.

Comment: Yeah, think he added that assertion after my answer. I'm still curious whether this isn't IO-bound rather than CPU-, and if it shouldn't then be using threads rather than processes.